# How to use empty string as default values for Int and Boolean

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Is there a way to create struct including fields that are optional. especially for boolean and Int but to not use defaults false/true or 0 for int?? Those are real values in our data.

I have this method to create a struct based on a case class schema. The schema is name:String, Id:Option[Int], status:Option[Boolean], title:String where Id and status are optional

```scala
  def buildKafkaStruct(): Struct = {
    val structRecord = new Struct(KAFKA_SCHEMA)
      .put("name", this.name)
      .put("Id", this.ID).getOrElse(null))
      .put("status", this.status).getOrElse(null))
      .put("title", this.title).getOrElse(""))
}
```

While testing this, if the record does not have Id or status field, having null as default works.

Test:

```scala
val jsonRecord = 
    {
            "name": "xyz",
            "title": "abc",
}
```

It returns struct Output:
Struct{name =xyz, title = abc} --> But this does not include other schema fields at all

The expected output is:

```
Struct{name =xyz, ID = , status = , title =}
```

I tried running it without null as default:

```scala
 def buildKafkaStruct(): Struct = {
    val structRecord = new Struct(KAFKA_SCHEMA)
      .put("name", this.name)
      .put("Id", this.ID).getOrElse("".toInt))
      .put("status", this.status).getOrElse("".toBoolean))
      .put("title", this.title).getOrElse(""))
}
```

Since the record does not have Id and status fields, it failed.